# Shouldn't JSON.parse(null) and JSON.parse(false) throw exceptions?

Tags: javascript, json

Argument to JSON.parse(...) is supposedly a valid json string, but null and false are not strings.

Note, I am passing javascript *null* not 'null' (as a string). Obviously JSON.parse('null') should work just fine.

```
JSON.parse(null) returns null?!
JSON.parse(false) returns null?!
```

Shouldn't they they throw exceptions?

```
JSON.parse(undefined) throws exception, as expected
JSON.parse('') throws exception, as expected
```

(Tested in recent Chrome and Firefox)

Comment: See [*JSON.org*](http://www.json.org), you can also do `JSON.parse(true)`, which returns `true`. Similarly `JSON.parse(false)` returns `false` and `JSON.parse(null)` returns `null`. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JSON.parse` [explicitly casts the argument to a string](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-json.parse). `null` results in the string `'null'` and `false` in the string `'false'`. `null` and `false` are valid JSON values, so they decode just fine.

Comment: This is dumb. You're right. But this is still dumb.

Comment: ‍♂️ It does *not* not make sense…

Comment: @XaxD—it makes sense in that it's consistent with the JSON standard, ECMA-404, more clearly explained at [*JSON.org*](http://www.json.org): "*A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or false or null, or an object or an array. These structures can be nested.*".

Comment: @RobG I don't think the spec for JSON values is related to this question